# client.get_channel(<VarWithTheChannelID>) ---> Error

Tags: python, discord.py

I just have a Discord.py Basics problem.

```
channel = client.get_channel(756582979471671397)
```

When I replace the channel id -> `756582979471671397` with a Var that I have defined before like that:

```
channelID = 756582979471671397
channel = client.get_channel(f'{channelID}')
```

I every time get an error...

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: @Nurqm It's a bit strange when I replace the Var for the ID i get an error for the next line in my code...
The error is:

     Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Anton\Documents\PythonBotDC\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 312, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:/Users/Anton/Documents/PythonBotDC/Homie Bot.py", line 32, in on_message
    msg1 = await channel.fetch_message(f'{message01}')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'fetch_message'

Comment: this is my hole code @Nurqm  
https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/694312636141011044/767030374998999090/ksjgfnhfkgln.PNG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

get_channel accepts an integer (see [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.get_channel)), so you should not try to pass a string.

This should work:

```
channelID = 756582979471671397
channel = client.get_channel(channelID)
```